# No result from options selected from a database column (php-mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

In the PHP code below i want to select all the column values of a table and make them options of a select form. The result is that i dont get any options at all. Could someone help? Thanks

```
<?php
// ....

$userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
echo "<select>";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where userid='".$userid."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo "<option>" .$row['company']. "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

mysqli_close();
?>
```

Comment: Try $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); to reveal errors.  Perhaps it's a connection error?  or your query might be getting no results.  $_SESSION['userid'] might not contain a value in your userid column in the users table in the database.  Those are some possibilities.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644950/no-result-from-options-selected-from-a-database-column-php-mysql @tom_yes_tom i tried $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); but there is no error message. I also tried to echo "$userid"; after $userid=$_SESSION['userid']; and there was correct number as a result. Also the company field has values for all the userid values. Thanks

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644950/no-result-from-options-selected-from-a-database-column-php-mysql) @tom_yes_tom the option values remain empty

Comment: When you check the resulting HTML page, are the option tags there but empty, or are they being created at all? If the query is valid but there are no results, you won't get an error. Try mysql_num_rows `($result)` to see if you are getting any results - then we'll know if its a database or code problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may just be a typo but you have mixed mysql and mysqli functions, you have stated mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array, whereas you have closed it with mysqli_close, could be an issue depending on what you wrote above this code or indeed if this is not just a typo.

Other things to try would be try the query in your mysql client / phpmyadmin and see if it comes up with any results or errors.